# Удаление повторов в БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Задача реализовать поиск по бд и нахождение повторов , но удалять  нужно не все повторы , а только те которые лежат в 1 категории (в роде кактегории свойств товаров)

```
p2.txt:

8557;360 г;299
8558;Рогалик;344
8559;Рогалик;344
8560;Батон;344
8561;Батон;344
8562;Батон;340
8563;Батон;340
8564;Intersnack;347
8565;Intersnack;347
8566;Повна Чаша;347
8567;Повна Чаша;347
8568;Булочка;344
8569;Булочка;344
```

```
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: petrov
 * Date: 5/19/15
 * Time: 5:15 PM
 */
class create
{
    public function getContent($file)
    {
        $lines = file_get_contents($file);

        $data = explode(PHP_EOL, $lines);
        return $data;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        $params = parse_ini_file('config.ini');


        if (!is_array($params)) {
            throw new Exception("Error #1");
        } else {
            $db = new PDO($params['db.conn'], $params['db.user'], $params['db.pass']);

        }
        return $db;
    }

    public function suit()
    {
        $db = $this->connect();
        $con = $this->getContent('p2.txt');


        for ($i = 0; count($con) > $i; $i++) {
            $correct = explode(";", $con[$i]);


            for ($a = 0; count($con) > $a; $a++) {
                $correct2 = explode(";", $con[$a]);

                if ($correct[0] !== $correct2[0] && $correct[1] == $correct2[1] && $correct[2] == $correct2[2]) {


                        $sql_update = "UPDATE ps_feature_product
                                  SET id_feature_value = :id_correct
                                  where id_feature_value = :id_fc and id_feature = :id_f";

                        $result = $db->prepare($sql_update);

                        $result->execute(
                            [
                                ':id_fc' => $correct2[0],
                                ':id_f' => $correct2[2],
                                ':id_correct' => $correct[0]
                            ]
                        );
                        $sql_delete = "DELETE
                                  FROM ps_feature_value_lang
                                  WHERE ps_feature_value_lang.id_feature_value = :id_f
                                  AND ps_feature_value_lang.id_lang = 1";

                        $result = $db->prepare($sql_delete);

                        $result->execute(
                            [
                                ':id_f' => $correct2[0],
                            ]
                        );


                }

            }


        }
    }

}

$cr = new create;
$cn2 = $cr->connect();
$cr->suit();
```

проблема: удаляет не 1 повтор, а все(т.е. и сам себя).

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `ps_feature_value_lang` limit 10;
+------------------+---------+--------+
| id_feature_value | id_lang | value  |
+------------------+---------+--------+
|             8416 |       1 | 1 кг   |
|             8421 |       1 | 100 г  |
|             8426 |       1 | 350 г  |
+------------------+---------+--------+
mysql> SELECT * FROM `ps_feature_product` limit 10;
+------------+------------+------------------+
| id_feature | id_product | id_feature_value |
+------------+------------+------------------+
|        299 |          4 |             8416 |
|        299 |          5 |             8416 |
|        299 |         26 |             8416 |
|        299 |         27 |             8416 |
+------------+------------+------------------+
mysql> SELECT * FROM `ps_feature_value` limit 10;
+------------------+------------+--------+
| id_feature_value | id_feature | custom |
+------------------+------------+--------+
|             8416 |        299 |      0 |
|             8421 |        299 |      0 |
|             8426 |        299 |      0 |
+------------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Логика у вас хромает, сильно-сильно. Вы мало того, что два раза по одному и тому же циклу бегаете, так вы еще и минимум два раза обновляете данные. И здесь вставки не вижу. Вам надо обновить существующие данные на основе данных файла? В вашем примере куча мусора, который практически не отображает суть вопроса. Т.е. весь код можно выбросить, это практически ничего не изменит для вопроса. Для примеров достаточно было бы привести пару полей таблицы и какие значения там хранятся.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что из таблицы `ps_feature_value_lang` надо удалить все записи кроме одной (например, 8426)? Если так, то можно сделать так: `DELETE target FROM ps_feature_value_lang AS target INNER JOIN ps_feature_value_lang AS source USING (id_lang) WHERE target.id_feature_value < source.id_feature_value AND target.id_lang = 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если требуется в каждой группе удалить всё, кроме одной (первой) записи, можно поступить так: группирующий подзапрос к той же таблице выдаст айдишники чего удалять нельзя. Таких записей будет ровно столько, сколько у нас групп. Всё прочее удаляем:

```
DELETE 
FROM `footable` AS f1
WHERE f1.`id` NOT IN(
  SELECT MIN(f2.`id`)
  FROM `footable` AS f2
  GROUP BY f2.`gr_field`
)
```

Если перед этим надо поправить внешние ссылки на эту таблицу, чтобы избежать "сирот", поступаем примерно также: находим айди правильной (первой) записи. Здесь будет параметрический подзапрос:

```
UPDATE `bartable` AS b
SET b.`foo_id` = (
  SELECT MIN(f.`id`)
  FROM `footable` AS f
  WHERE f.`gr_field` = b.`gr_field`
)
```

После чего можно и нужно создать уникальный индекс, чтобы предотвратить накопление новых ошибок.

**UPDATE**: как справедливо заметили в комментариях, MySQL не нравится запрос на удаление со ссылкой на себя. Но это легко обходится дополнительной "прокладкой":

```
DELETE FROM `footable`
WHERE `id` NOT IN(
  SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT MIN(`id`)
        FROM `footable`
        GROUP BY `gr_field`
  ) AS f2
)
```

Comment: А с каких пор в mysql разрешены такие запросы на удаление? В 5.5 это ошибка (`ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table ... for update in FROM clause`). Работает только вариант через `JOIN` (см. пример в моем комментарии к ответу)

Comment: Вы правы, отчасти. Я забыл, что MySQL нужно обманывать, заворачивая подзапрос еще в одну обертку:

    DELETE FROM `footable`
    WHERE `id` NOT IN(
      SELECT f2.`id`
      FROM (
      SELECT MIN(`id`) AS `id`
      FROM `footable`
      GROUP BY `sup`
      ) AS f2
    )

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER IGNORE table `tbl_name` ADD unique `fld_name`;
```

Добавление уникального индекса на поле удалит все записи, где поле содержит повторы. Ключевое слово `IGNORE` избавит от ругани.

Имейте, однако, в виду, что

> As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error.

[Похожий вопрос на аглийском.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456520/)

Comment: Это свойство прикриплено к товару, например Рогалик марки Повна Чаша например, т.е мне нужно обязателно сохранить 1 свойство убрав дубликаты и перебрать, если у дубликата товары прекреплины то поменять на id главного(тот который мы оставим главным из всех дублей). И затем только удаляем дубли. Сначало update потом delete.

Comment: @msim, если вас дубликаты совсем не интересуют, то может тогда сделать поле `UNIQUE`, а при вставке делать как-то так: `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = id`? Тогда если такая запись уже есть, то новая не добавится. Тогда и удалять ничего не надо будет.

Comment: согласен, но как раз мне нужно очистить от дублей, т.к. уже сущ база есть на 10000 записей только свойств. Соответственно потом unique на value поставлю

Comment: @msim, самым простым вариантом было создание временной таблицы нужной структуры (с уникальным индексом) и вставка в нее старых значений (`INSERT INTO SELECT * FROM... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`). После этого во временной таблице у вас были бы только необходимые данные. Осталось бы очистить старую таблицу и вставить туда записи из временной таблицы (ну либо удалить старую и переименовать новую)

Comment: а как быть с зависимостью  id_feature | id_product | id_feature_value и завязкой под товар как мне там все поменять? т.е.  id_feature_value мы удаляем во временной , ура дубля нет, но теперь товар привязан к несущ свойству

Comment: @msim, для этого есть [внешние ключи](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). При удалении внешней записи будет удалена (или обновлена) текущая. Правда из-за этого удалять все записи в исходной таблице не получится (т.к. удалятся и нужные нам свойства), но можно будет удалить все записи, которых нет в новой (временной) таблице. Либо использовать другой способ.

Comment: @BOPOH скажи пожалуйста а реализовать это с помощью  INSERT ... SELECThttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html реально, просто мне подсказали еще и такой вариант

Comment: @msim, я выше в комментарии как раз приводил пример с `INSERT... SELECT...`. Но к удалению это не имеет никакого отношения, поэтому лучше возникшие вопросы задать отдельно.