# Как заменить данные выбранных строк данными из других строк в той же самой таблице?

Tags: mysql, sql

Более длиная формулировка: как заменить данные некоторых полей выбранных строк соответствующими данными из полей других строк **в той же самой таблице**?

Создал тестовую таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `pk` int unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fk` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field_1` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field_2` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `field_3` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`pk`)
);
```

Наполнил ее данными:

```
INSERT INTO test
    (`fk`, `field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3`)
VALUE
    (1, 111, 'a', 'one'),
    (2, 222, 'b', 'two'),
    (2, 333, 'c', 'three'),
    (2, 444, 'd', 'four'),
    (3, 555, 'e', 'five'),
    (3, 666, 'f', 'six'),
    (3, 777, 'g', 'seven'),
    (3, 888, 'h', 'eight'),
    (3, 999, 'i', 'nine');
```

Как получить таблицу из такими даными:

```
+----+----+---------+---------+---------+
| pk | fk | field_1 | field_2 | field_3 |
+----+----+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 |  1 |     111 | a       | one     |
|  2 |  2 |     555 |         | five    |
|  3 |  2 |     666 |         | six     |
|  4 |  2 |     777 |         | seven   |
|  5 |  3 |     555 | e       | five    |
|  6 |  3 |     666 | f       | six     |
|  7 |  3 |     777 | g       | seven   |
|  8 |  3 |     888 | h       | eight   |
|  9 |  3 |     999 | i       | nine    |
+----+----+---------+---------+---------+
```

Т.е. как заменить данные полей строк, где `fk` равен 2, соотвествующими полями строк, где `fk` равен 3 в последовательности в соответствии с `pk`? Значения полей `pk` и `fk` не надо менять. Желательно это сделать одним запросом.

**P.S.** В реальном случае еще надо **не** менять данные поля `field_2`, т.е. этим полям присвоить значение по умолчанию. Но так как количество строк при замене может быть не одинаковым, то думаю перед заменой лучше сделать один дополнительный запрос для присвоения значения по умолчанию полям строк, где `fk` равен 2.

Попытался сначала заменить данные из поля `field_1` следующими запросами:

```
UPDATE
    test AS a
SET
    a.field_1=(SELECT b.field_1 FROM test AS b WHERE b.fk=3)
WHERE
    a.fk=2;
```

Вывело ошибку:

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause
```

Т.е. невозможно изменить поля таблицы, с которой осуществляется выборка.

```
UPDATE
    test AS a
INNER JOIN
    test AS b
ON
    a.fk=2 AND b.fk=3
SET
    a.field_1=b.field_1
WHERE
    a.fk=2;
```

Этот запрос к сожалению заменил тремя одинаковыми значениями 555, 555 и 555, вместо 555, 666 и 777.

Также пробовал создать соотвествующий `REPLACE` запрос, но не удалось с помощью него получить нужный результат.

Comment: боюсь, средствами sql такая задача нереализуема. нужно в цикле проходить по выдаче двух запросов (один — `where fk=2`, другой — `where fk=3`) и либо на каждом шаге выполнять `update`, либо собирать информацию и выполнить один «сборный» `update` после окончания цикла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нумеруем записи с fk=2 и с fk=3 отдельно, связываем их по полученному номеру, из fk=2 берем pk (для идентификации записи), из fk3 - поля, которые будем апдейтить:

```
set @a2=0;
set @a3=0;
update test 
join 
  (select t2.pk, t3.field_1, t3.field_2, t3.field_3  
   from 
     ( select @a2:=@a2+1 t2id, pk
       from test
         where fk = 2
       order by pk) t2
     left join (
       select @a3:=@a3+1 t3id, field_1, field_2, field_3 
       from test
         where fk = 3
       order by pk) t3
     on t2.t2id = t3.t3id
  ) tt using (pk)
set
test.field_1 = ifnull(tt.field_1, test.field_1),
test.field_2 = ifnull(tt.field_2, test.field_2),
test.field_3 = ifnull(tt.field_3, test.field_3);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87344/1

Comment: Всё хорошо, кроме field_2. У автора специальная оговорка про это поле.

Comment: @artoodetoo постскриптумы не читаю :) будем считать: для самостоятельного выполнения.

Answer (score 1):

`You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause`
в MySQL фактически означает просьбу завернуть подзапрос в еще один слой :)

Например вот здесь обходится данная проблема: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425078/176610
смотрите дописку в конце ответа.

Или вот на английском два варианта: `multi-table update` или `subquery`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45498/272885

Comment: Ошибку это обходит, но задачу-то все равно не решает - результат будет равен последнему варианту автора (если еще запрос правильно оформить).

Answer (score 1):

Еще один ответ т.к. автор фактически задал два вопроса. На этот раз про то как найти соответствие строк.

Язык SQL не полагается на порядок записей, он оперирует множествами и отношениями. Чтобы указать соответствие типа "первая отсюда и первая оттуда", нам придется добавить недостающую колонку с этим порядковым номером. Есть например такой рецепт нумерации на SO: [number per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939198/row-number-per-group-in-mysql).
С помощью переменных мы создаем вычисляемую колонку с номером. Результат можно сохранить в промежуточную таблицу. Достаточно TEMPORARY TABLE, которая умрет сама после закрытия соединения, но у sqlfiddle свои особнности поэтому я создал пример с постоянной таблицей:

```
CREATE TABLE test2 AS (
SELECT 
  a.*,
  @row := IF(fk = @fk, @row + 1, 1) AS row,
  @fk := fk AS fk2
FROM 
  test AS a,
  (SELECT @row := 0, @fk := 0) r
ORDER BY fk
);
```

Теперь, имея номера строк, мы можем поколдовать с само-объединением:

```
SELECT 
  a.pk,
  a.fk,
  IFNULL(b.field_1, a.field_1) AS field_1,
  IF(b.field_2 IS NOT NULL, '', a.field_2) AS field_2,
  IFNULL(b.field_3, a.field_3) AS field_3
FROM 
  test2 AS a LEFT JOIN
  test2 AS b ON (a.fk = 2) AND (b.fk = 3) AND (a.row = b.row)
ORDER BY a.pk
```

Этот запрос выводит ту табличку, что вы хотели. См. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a862b/1
Можете апдейтить им изначальную таблицу.

```
UPDATE 
  test t1 JOIN
  (здесь предыдущий запрос) t2 USING(pk)
SET
  t1.field1=t2.field1,
  t1.field2=t2.field2,
  t1.field3=t2.field3
```

Answer (score 1):

> соответствующими полями строк

Соответствующими, Карл!

Но в таблице нигде не прописано соответствие. То есть, никаких "соответствующих" полей на самом деле нету, они существуют только в воображении пользователя. И костыли из соседнего ответа не помогут. Если решать бессмысленную задачу буквально, то ты получим бессмысленный же ответ.

Поэтому надо либо прописать соответствия (банальный parent_id), либо - что ещё лучше - **задать нормальный вопрос по исходной задаче**, а не просить починить костыль, который ты выдумал для ее решения.

Comment: Ваш ответ полон ненависти. Лучшее, что вы можете сделать — удалить его. А затем, если порыв еще останется, написать комментарий к вопросу или к ответу-костылю.